# Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function in row concatenation

Tags: sql-server, substring, charindex

i'm getting "Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function" error on this function, it takes numbers from strings like "Abracadabra {34}" or doesn't take if string has no "{}". 
I have a "CASE", but it seems like it doesn't work properly. 
Certainly it works perfectly with typical case - "Abracadabra {34}", but because of complicated condition in query i can't check this function with another cases. 
Maybe you could find mistake, just by taking a look.
Please help me.

```
CREATE FUNCTION func (
@nidop int
)
RETURNS varchar
BEGIN
DECLARE @sreturn varchar(1000);
SET @sreturn = '';
 SELECT 
 @sreturn = CASE CHARINDEX('{', wp.description) 
 WHEN 0 THEN @sreturn
 ELSE
 @sreturn + SUBSTRING(wp.description, CHARINDEX('{', wp.description) + 1,
 CHARINDEX('}', wp.description) - CHARINDEX('{', wp.description) - 1) + ','
 END 
 FROM
 (/*some select*/) ttt, RB_WORKPLACE wp
 WHERE wp.classified = ttt.ap 
ORDER BY CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('{', wp.[description]) > 0 THEN 
CONVERT(INT, 
SUBSTRING(wp.[description],
          CHARINDEX('{', wp.[description]) + 1,
          CHARINDEX('}', wp.[description]) - CHARINDEX('{', wp.[description]) - 1)
 )
 ELSE 0 
END;
 SET @sreturn = SUBSTRING(@sreturn, 1, LEN(@sreturn) - 1)
 RETURN @sreturn;
END;
```

I will try to give more information about issue. In this function i'm trying to migrate another function from Oracle:

```
create or replace function func(nidop in number) return varchar2 as
  sreturn varchar2(1000);  
begin
  select listagg(to_number(substr(wp.description, instr(wp.description, '{') + 1,
                                   instr(wp.description, '}') - instr(wp.description, '{') - 1)), ',') within group(order by to_number(substr(wp.description, instr(wp.description, '{') + 1, instr(wp.description, '}') - instr(wp.description, '{') - 1)))
    into sreturn
    from (/*some select*/) ttt, workplace wp
   where wp.classified = ttt.ap;
    return sreturn;

exception
  when others then
    return null;
end func;
```

Temporaly I changed this not-mine query, to "xml path('')" like query, thanks all for help. Only one item was because of returning varchar instead of varchar(50) for example.(In my case)

Comment: You should be aware that `SELECT @local_variable = some function of @local_variable` is not a *reliable* way to perform concatenation. The documentation specifically warns that there's no guarantee that the expression is evaluated once and only once for each row.

Comment: And scalar functions are horribly inefficient. You should consider changing to an inline table valued function instead of a scalar.

Comment: Another suggestion is to use ANSI-92 style joins instead of the antiquated version of joins you are using here. You also have clearly left out an important piece of this code because you have a parameter but it is not referenced anywhere in the code you posted.

Comment: @SeanLange 
1)But i need to use result string, is it OK?
2)I left a big select, without error functions, i'm sorry, but maybe it gives information about company struucture.
3)I read information about ANSI-92, and i got it, thank you. Now  i will use ANSI-92(I am not very experienced developer) in futre, although it's not mine query fully, but i don't think it could solve problem in that case.

Comment: Yes you can get the result from a table valued function. That is the point of them. Just make sure you don't use a multi-statement table valued function or your performance will go out the window again. From what you posted this should be easily done as a single select statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is coming from your ORDER BY clause. You do not have it wrapped in a condition (`CASE` or `IIF`) like you have in the SELECT. Change your ORDER BY to be the following:

```
 ORDER BY CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('{', wp.[description]) > 0 THEN 
 CONVERT(INT, 
    SUBSTRING(wp.[description],
              CHARINDEX('{', wp.[description]) + 1,
              CHARINDEX('}', wp.[description]) - CHARINDEX('{', wp.[description]) - 1)
     )
     ELSE 0 
    END;
```

Also, it is not a good idea to specify the return type as simply `VARCHAR` without a length. The default width of a `VARCHAR` / `NVARCHAR` is either 1 or 30, depending on the context in which it is being stated. Since your local variable is declared as `VARCHAR(1000)`, you should use the same 1000 for the declaration of the output type.

Comment: Yes, there was a mistake, but not the main. I added order by clause   after problem being discussed. But thank you very much, i think i need to change my post now.

Comment: @Nixton, I am confused now. After I added the CASE statement I stopped getting the error. Although now I see that only 1 item ever shows up in `@sreturn`, but that is a different issue.

Comment: But I did not stopped :(
Yeah, in SSMA debug at last line of function i'm getting full string, but somehow when gettting only 1 item in select. Do I need create different topic for this issue?

Comment: Temporaly I changed this not-mine query, to "xml path('')" like query, thanks all for help.
Only one item was because of returning varchar instead of varchar(50) for example.(In my case)